# If instances are really just pointers to objects in Python, what happens when I change the value of a data attribute in a particular instance?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I define "Class original:" and create a class attribute "one = 4." Then I create an instance of the class "First = original()." My understanding is that First now contains a pointer to original and "First.one" will return "4." However, suppose I create "Second = original()" and then set "Second.one = 5." What exactly happens in memory? Does a new copy of Class original get created with a class attribute of 5?

I've created a Class original with class attribute one. I then created two instances of this class (First and Second) and verified that id(First.one) and id(Second.one) are pointing to the same place. They both return the same address. However, when I created Third=original() and set Third.one = 5 and then check id(Thrid.one) it appears to be pointing somewhere else. Where is it pointing and what happened? When I check original.one it still returns "4" so obviously the original object is not being modified. Thanks.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand what you are talking about if you actually posted the code instead of describing it in essay form. We are programmers, not literature critics (they are over there: [literature.se]), we prefer seeing the code instead of reading about it. I *think* I understand what you are asking, but it took me about an hour!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are asking about a piece of code similar to this:

```py
class Original:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.one = n

first  = Original(4)
second = Original(4)

third  = Original(5)

print(id(first.one))
# 140570468047360

print(id(second.one))
# 140570468047360

print(id(third.one))
# 140570468047336
```

> Suppose I define "Class original:" and create a class attribute "one = 4." Then I create an instance of the class "First = original()." My understanding is that First now contains a pointer to original

No. The variable references the instance you created, not the class. If it referenced the class, there would be *no way* for you to get at the instance you just created.

The *instance* will, somewhere in its object header, of course contain a pointer to its class. Without that pointer, method lookup wouldn't be possible, since you wouldn't be able to find the class from the instance.

> and "First.one" will return "4."

Yes. The attribute `one` of `first` contains a pointer to the object `4` (which is an instance of the class `int`).

[Note that technically, some Python implementations will perform an optimization and actually store the object `4` directly in the attribute instead of a pointer to the object. But that is an internal implementation detail.]

> However, suppose I create "Second = original()" and then set "Second.one = 5." What exactly happens in memory? Does a new copy of Class original get created with a class attribute of 5?

No. Why would you need a separate copy of the class? The methods are still the same for both instances. In fact, that is *precisely* the reason why methods in Python take the instance as their first argument! That way, there need only be one method. (This is actually the same in every OO language, except that in most other languages, this argument is "invisible" and only accessible using a special keyword like `self` in Ruby, Smalltalk, Self, and Newspeak or `this` in Java, C#, and Scala.)

> I've created a Class original with class attribute one. I then created two instances of this class (First and Second) and verified that id(First.one) and id(Second.one) are pointing to the same place. They both return the same address. However, when I created Third=original() and set Third.one = 5 and then check id(Thrid.one) it appears to be pointing somewhere else.

It is not quite clear to me what your question is here. `first.one` and `second.one` both point to `4`, so they both point to the same ID since they both point to the same object. `third.one` points to `5`, which is obviously a different object from `4`, so naturally, it has a different ID.

It is, in fact, one of the requirement of IDs that different objects that exist at the same time *must* have different IDs.

> Where is it pointing and what happened?

Again, it is not quite clear what you are asking.

It is pointing at `5`, and nothing happened.

> When I check original.one it still returns "4" so obviously the original object is not being modified.

Indeed, it isn't. Why would it be?